# Is it thread-safe to access a Mat with multiple threads in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing

i want to speedup an algorithm (complete local binary pattern with circle neighbours) for which i iterate trough all pixels and calculate some stuff with it neighbours (so i need neighbour pixel access).

Currently i do this by iterating over all pixels with one thread/process. I want to parallelize this task by dividing the input image into multiple ROIs and calculate each ROI seperatly (with multiple threads).

The Problem here is, that the ROIs are overlapping (because to calculate a pixel, sometimes i need to look at neighbours far away) and its possible that multiple threads accessing Pixel-Data (**READING**) at same time. Is that a Problem if two or more threads reading same Mat at same Indices at same time?

Is it also a problem, if i write to the same Mat parallel but at different indices?

Comment: Will all of your threads only be reading from the `Mat`?  Do note that  this approach may suffer from [false sharing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads)

Comment: @NathanOliver i will both read and write, but write will be done on a different Output Mat and non overlapping Indices. Read instead will be done with the input Mat and overlapping indices of that Mat. PS: Thanks for your link, but i will work only on one CPU with multi-threading (Intel i5).

Comment: Your i5 isn't a single CPU.  It might be a single chip, but there are multiple CPU cores on it and so you do have to absolutely worry about false sharing.

Comment: Unless the documentation clearly states the way for thread safety, don't assume anything.

Comment: @MathLibrary Yes, Nathan is right about that. By the way, can you show an example code of how you are selecting a ROI, how you intend to read and how you intend to write? This is important, because I've been working with OpenCV on different platforms and it is hard to give a definitive answer without trying, to say the least.

Comment: @NathanOliver ah ok, i tought the are talking about different CPUs, not different Cores inside same CPU. I will have a look at the link. Thanks. Do you know, if writing to same Mat (but different indices) by multiple threads is also bad?

Comment: @MathLibrary It depends on the implementation.

Comment: I presume you want to parallelise to improve performance. If so, you may find it is better to show your actual code because a) there are some very talented folk on Stack Overflow who may be able to help you and b) for loops are rarely the way to get best performance out of OpenCV.

Comment: Oh and also, can you please share your OpenCV version. (2.X or 3.X ?)

Comment: I'm not familiar with opencv so I can't say for certain but I know for things like a `std::vector` as long as you aren't changing the size of the container then it should be safe to update the individual elements as long as only one thread writes to a particular index.  If I were you I would wait for an authoritative answer.

Comment: Ok i will soon update post with some Code. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 3):

As long as *no* writes happen simultaneously to the reads, it is safe to have multiple concurrent reads.

That holds for any sane system.

Consider the alternative:

If there was a race condition, it would mean that the memory storing your object gets modified during the read operation. If no memory (storing the object) gets written to during the read, there's no possible interaction between the threads.

Lastly, if you look at the doc,

https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html

You'll see two mentions of thread-safety:

> Thus, it is safe to operate on the same matrices asynchronously in
>   different threads.

They mention it around ref-counting, performed during matrix assignment. So, at the very least, assigning from the same matrix to two others can be done safely in multiple threads. This pretty much guarantees that simple read access is also thread-safe.

Comment: To be honest I dont know why this is downvoted. Dude's got the point! Some may find it helpful! Parallel reading wont cause problems with mulithreading. If there's a contract that `cv::Mat` stays immutable (at least during reading) this should be fine.

Comment: @Jeffrey Thanks much for your comment. It helped me at least for the "reading"-part of my algo.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, parallel reading is not a problem as a `cv::Mat` is just a nice wrapper around an array, just like `std::vector` (yes there are differences but I don't see how they would affect the matter of the topic here so I'm going to ignore them). However parallelization doesn't automatically give you a performance boost. There are quite a few things to consider here:

Creating a thread is ressource heavy and can have a large negative impact if the task is relatively short (in terms of computation time) so thread pooling has to be considered.

If you write high performance code (no matter if multi- or single threaded) you should have a grasp of how your hardware works. In this case: memory and CPU. There is a [very good talk](https://youtu.be/BP6NxVxDQIs) from Timur Doumler at CppCon 2016 about that topic. This should help you avoiding cache misses.

Also mention worthy is compiler optimization. Turn it on. I know this sounds super obvious but there are a lot of people on SO that ask questions about performance and yet they don't know what compiler optimization is.

Finally, there is the OpenCV Transparent API (TAPI) which basically utilizes the GPU instead of the CPU. Almost all built-in algorithms of OpenCV support the TAPI, you just have to pass a `cv::UMat` instead of a `cv::Mat`. Those two types are convertible to each other. However, the conversion is time intensive because a `UMat` is basically an array on the GPU memory (VRAM), which means it has to be copied each time you convert it. Also accessing the VRAM takes longer than accessing the RAM (for the CPU that is). 
Though, you have to keep in mind that you cannot access VRAM data with the CPU without copying it to the RAM. This means you cannot iterate over your pixels if you use `cv::UMat`. It is only possible if you write your own OpenCL or Cuda code so your algorithm can run on the GPU.

In most consumer grade PCs, for sliding window algorithms (basically anything that iterates over the pixels and performs a calculation around each pixel), using the GPU is usually by far the fastest method (but also requires the most effort to implement). Of course this only holds if the data buffer (your image) is large enough to make it worth copying to and from the VRAM.

For parallel writing: it's generally safe as long as you don't have overlapping areas. However, cache misses and [false sharing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads) (as pointed out by NathanOliver) are problems to be considered.

Comment: Can you elaborate how false sharing is a problem for multiple *reads* ?  I'm under the impression that the reads on CPU and GPU wouldn't trigger cache misses for other cores. Nothing prevents the same memory from being L1 cached in multiple cores.

Comment: @Jeffrey good catch that is indeed not a problem in read-only operations. Fixed. Note that there is no cache on a GPU so false sharing and cache misses aren't a problem there.

Comment: @Timo Thanks for the answer. Unfortunally im not using a GPU and also my algorithm will be used on different CPUs (Intel, ARM and AMD), so writing Parallel Code exactly optimized on one CPU/hardware as you mentioned is not possible and generally not a good Idea i think (because hard to port code). Im currently surveying which Parallel Library is good (which supports most CPU Architectures).

Comment: @MathLibrary I never said to optimize for a specific CPU. As long as your system has RAM and the CPU in question has a cache all I wrote applies.